# When uploading image to server:front camera photo works/rear camera photo doesn't

Tags: php, android

I have an app in which I select an image and I upload it successfully. My problem is that I can only upload selfies-front camera photos. If I select a photo which was taken with the rear camera I get an error from the server telling me that it hasn't received any file because this line returns false `if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']))`. How can I solve this ?

I checked in the gallery and both have the same format: JPEG.

This is my php.

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = "IP";

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    // reading other post parameters
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;
    $response['website'] = $website;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Could it be a size problem?  If you have a max file upload size, a rear facing camera tends to be higher res thus bigger files.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked... php limit upload_max_filesize is set to 2 MB.

Comment: That's gonna be an issue.

Comment: I'm just using it for testing.. it's free. Well now I know it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the size of the image.

Front camera has a smaller quality = smaller size.

The php excepts files as form data and if the file size exceeds the upload limit.

Check the "upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size" in phpinfo(). 
Test if you increase both values will it upload.